# Servlet and JSF page within same context shows different sessions

Tags: servlets, jsf-2

We have a need to make a call to a servlet from an external application which is making a post request.

The servlet looks at the request, performs some processing and sets a attribute on the request or session and redirects to a JSF page which needs to retrieve the attribute set on the request or the session and do additional stuff.

For both cases I have been unable to retrieve the attribute/parameter set on the session or request from the managed bean and upon further debugging, it revealed that the session ids were different in servlet and in the managed bean.

Since this is a request coming from an external application, there is no session in the servlet so doing request.getSession(true); which is creating a new session in the servlet.

I was under the understanding that since these were part of the same application and using the same context that they would have the same session. Is my understanding incorrect?
Is there a better solution to this issue? (I did consider creating a Filter but thought might have the same issue with the session)

Any help in understanding better or resolving this issue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As to how sessions work, carefully read this: [How do servlets work? Instantiation, sessions, shared variables and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-session-variables-and-multithreading/3106909#3106909).

In fact, the external application should have sent the very same session cookie as the JSF application is using. An alternative would have been to provide a callback URL including the `jsessionid` path fragment, which is composed as follows:

```
String url = "http://example.com/context/servlet;jsessionid=" + session.getId();
```

Again another alternative would be to generate an unique ID (with `java.util.UUID`) referencing an entry in application scope or even the DB and set it as request parameter in the callback URL. You should only manually cleanup it when the session is destroyed. You can use a HTTP session listener for that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response BalusC.
Currently as a POC, the external application is a html page doing a form submit doing a POST request to my servlet. 

I read the post about how sessions work but that still did not help me understand why there were two separate sessions between my servlet and the page it redirected to within the same context.

BTW, big fan of yours! You have indirectly helped me understand and solve some of my JSF related issues over the years.

Comment: I do understand the workarounds you are suggesting but want to get to the workaround if it is really needed. In my mind I have the assumption that the servlet and the JSF page should share the same session as they are part of the same application and same context as well. Is my assumption incorrect? Is there a way an external application can make a POST request to a JSF page?

Comment: The session is not tied to the whole server, but to the client (the enduser using the application). It look like that you're mixing "application scope" with "session scope".

Comment: I should clarify where the initial request is coming from. Its an inbound request from an external app we dont have control over. Kind of an SSO related solution where we get the relevant information from the request and process it and signing on if it matches our criteria. I was able to process this information in my managed bean without using a servlet and was able to do that. Taking to the secure area after authentication is giving me trouble again with the session as the session did not really originate from a client. Will check on spring security forum as well. Other alternatives?